# Como Executar um procedimento a cada insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Quando eu vou fazer um cadastro eu quero de acordo com a categoria selecionada gravar um id do moderador, na tabela de pergunta.

```html
select idcategoria from tb_pergunta
select idmoderador,idcategoria from tb_moderador


USE [BANCOTESTE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ATUALIZAMODERADOR]    Script Date: 06/15/2015 13:14:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ATUALIZAMODERADOR]
 @IDPERGUNTA INT 
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @IDCATEGORIA INT
 DECLARE @IDMODERADOR INT

 SELECT  @IDCATEGORIA = IDCATEGORIA FROM TB_PERGUNTA WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA
 SELECT  @IDMODERADOR = IDMODERADOR FROM TB_MODERADOR WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @IDCATEGORIA
 UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA SET  IDMODERADOR = @IDMODERADOR, BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA='N', EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA='N'  WHERE IDPERGUNTA = @IDPERGUNTA

END
```

Comment: Amarre sua procedure a uma trigger na tabela

Comment: @gmsantos A criação ficaria desta forma? tem outra forma de fazer? fiz a alteração do código da pergunta, agradeço

Comment: Seria algo assim mesmo. Não vou poder verificar a fundo agora mas parece que está certo sim.

Comment: @gmsantos - Deu certo, eu fiz  alteração do código é postei novamente, muito grato a sua ajuda!

Comment: edite sua pergunta, extraindo a solução como resposta e deixando a dúvida inicial somente como pergunta. Não tem problema em responder a sua própria pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

A solução seria a criação de uma triggers

A criação ficaria desta forma:

insert into tb_pergunta values ('1','1','','titulo pergunta','descricao','','','')

```html
USE [BANCOTESTE]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TGR_TB_PERGUNTA]    Script Date: 06/15/2015 15:11:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_TB_PERGUNTA]
 ON [dbo].[TB_PERGUNTA]
 FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @IDCATEGORIA INT
   DECLARE @IDMODERADOR INT

   SELECT  @IDCATEGORIA = IDCATEGORIA FROM INSERTED
   SELECT  @IDMODERADOR = IDMODERADOR FROM TB_MODERADOR WHERE IDCATEGORIA = @IDCATEGORIA
   UPDATE TB_PERGUNTA SET  IDMODERADOR = @IDMODERADOR, BLOQUEIO_PERGUNTA='N', EXCLUIR_PERGUNTA='N'  
END
```